# Upgrading an Arduino Duemilanove from ATMega168 to ATMega328

Tags: arduino, atmega

I have purchased an [ATMega328](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9217?) from SparkFun with the Arduino bootloader pre-programmed.  My intention is to replace the ATMega168 I currently have in my Duemilanove.  Is this as simple as swapping the chips, or will I need to take any additional steps?  As I recall, I am currently at Arduino 13 but am planning to upgrade to 17 (current version) concurrent with the part swap.

Comment: The upgrade went without a hitch!  I realized I had Arduino 12 installed, however, so I had to change things up a bit:

-Upgraded Arduino software to version 17 (most recent).
-Set up software to work with the current chip (the 168).  Verified that communications were working.*
-Upgraded the Arduino hardware to an ATMega328p with the Arduino bootloader previously flashed (from Sparkfun).
-Verified the software and hardware still played together nicely.

*The communication worked, but my software ran out of RAM.  I only wanted to verify communication, so I wasn't concerned by this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you may simply switch the chips.  Version 13 implemented support for the 328, so an IDE upgrade is not essential.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you change the "Tools/Board" setting in the Arduino IDE to "Arduino Duemilanove or Nano w/ Atmega328"

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can just swap it in. I've also upgraded a Diecimila without any problems. If you have an AVR programmer (such as the one from Adafruit) you can also upgrade it with a fresh unprogrammed chip.